# How to pass argument values in the program implementing the shell

Tags: c, shell, ubuntu, parameters, arguments

**SOURCE::**

```
#include <stdio.h> // printf()
#include <stdlib.h> // exit()
#include <string.h> // string
#include <dirent.h> // microsoft base compiler. _chdir, _getcwd
#include <unistd.h> // unix base complier. getcwd, chdir
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

#define FILE_SIZE       1024
#define MAX 255
#define ERROR       (-1)

void cmd_mkdir(int argc, char *argv);

void cmd_ls()
{
    char * cwd = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 1024);
    DIR * dir = NULL;
    struct dirent * entry = NULL;
    getcwd(cwd, 1024);
    if( (dir = opendir(cwd)) == NULL)
    {
        printf("current directory error\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    while( (entry = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s\n", entry->d_name);
    }
    free(cwd);
    closedir(dir);
}

void cmd_pwd() {
    char buf[MAX];

    getcwd(buf, MAX);
    printf("%s\n", buf);
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{   
    char cBuf[MAX];
    char *arg;

    while(1) { 
        printf(">> "); 
        arg = fgets(cBuf, MAX, stdin);

        if(argc < 2){
        // printf("1111\n"); -- check
            if(strncmp(arg, "ls", 2) == 0)
            cmd_ls();
        else if(strncmp(arg, "pwd", 3) == 0)
            cmd_pwd();
        else if(strncmp(arg, "exit", 4) == 0)
            break;
        } // if END
        else {
        // printf("2222\n"); -- check
        if(strcmp(arg, "mkdir") == 0){
            if (argc != 2)
                fprintf(stderr, "Usage : jmkdir dirname\n");

                if(mkdir(argv[1], 0755))
                perror("mkdir error");
                }
        }// else END

    } // while END
} // main END
```

**Desired result::**
How to get two input values (`mkdir`, `mini_maked`) as parameters after executing `./minishell` (executable file implementing the shell)

```
$ ./minishell
>> mkdir mini_maked
```

Currently implemented `ls, pwd, exit` can be implemented because it can be used without options, but a command that requires a "command filename" such as `mkdir` is not implemented.

If the program itself functions as `mkdir`, it is solved using the values of **argc** and **argv**.

However, since the `./myshell` program itself implements the **shell** program, when you run the program and receive `mkdir mini_maked` as an input, you are having a hard time executing the command.

If we get two inputs (`mkdir`, `mini_maked`) after program execution, how do we get these as parameters?

Comment: After you read a command line, you need to split it into separate words.  For a toy shell like this, it is probably sufficient to split the line on whitespace.  This gives you some number greater than zero of strings, the first of which is the command name, and the rest of which are command-line arguments and/or operators (if your shell recognizes any operators).  Beyond that, it's not clear to me what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you for modifying your proposal. And as you said, I solved it using strtok. Thank you so much and it was helpful.

Comment: If solved please add an answer with solution and when possible accept it. This helps to select solved and unsolved questions.